# Android MediaPlayer Question

Tags: android, media-player

```
public class PlayAudio extends BroadcastReceiver{
       private Context mContext;
        MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mContext = context;
    mIntent = intent;
    playSound("sound.mp3");

    }

       private void playSound(String file){
           mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, Uri.parse("file://"+file));
           if (mp.isPlaying())
           {
              mp.stop();
           }

                mp.setLooping(true);
                try {
                   mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                mp.start();
        }

}
```

I am getting an error when i check if mp is playing. How can i check if MediaPlayer(mp) is playing so that i can stop it?

Comment: what error you are getting, please show the logcat.

Comment: Have you checked the variable mp is not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a bit of confusion in the above code
In the above code new instance of media player will get created each time you call playsound()  what you need to do is instantiate mp only once in oncreate() of playaudio class and use it repeatedly.

Also if you use create to instantiate mediaplayer you prepare gets called internally you should not call it again.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri)

Check if mp is null after you do create to verify if mediaplayer instance was created successfully.

Comment: i did what you adviced me to do. I check if mp is null. if not then i check if mp.isPlaying() is true. But i always get that mp.isPlaying() is false.

Comment: if you haven't moved the media player create part to oncreate of the class then you will get mp.isplaying() as false always because you creating new instance of mediaplayer every time which is not yet playing.

Comment: what i did in order to fix this problem is to create a service that is called by my Broadcast receiver. In the service i start and stop the MediaPlayer